# Am I using pointers and array correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My teacher for an assignment problems requires that we pass an array to a function that just finds the median of it. and if there's an even amount of numbers, it averages the two in the middle. I quote from him "use pointers whenever possible". The only one I could see using a pointer is the array itself?

I understand the concept of what needs to happen, I'm just not sure how to properly use pointers and Googling doesn't reveal too helpful results.

```
int medianArray(int *pArray, int sizeArray)
{
    if(sizeArray % 2 == 1)
    {
        return (pArray[((int)(sizeArray/2)) -1 ] + pArray[((int)(sizeArray/2)) +1 ]) / 2;
    }
    else
        return pArray[(int) sizeArray/2];
}
```

Comment: A C++ teacher that says "use pointers whenever possible" is almost completely missing the point of C++. That's a shame.

Comment: I am confused, elaborate? Is there a difference between using a pointer to pass an array and passing the array itself? I thought the only difference was the amount of memory/space it took up.

Comment: @tadman - While C++ guides discourage use of pointers, standard library iterators work very similarly - it *could* be that the exercise is intended to prepare for doing the same thing with iterators. I'm not sure it's *likely*, but we could give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Tell your teacher it would be better to use a vector

Comment: Modern C++ encourages passing references or cheap copies whenever possible, as pointers add considerable amounts of complexity. A reference is never NULL, it can safely be presumed valid, and doesn't have an owner. Pointers can refer to things that get deleted, and maintaining an ownership chain in C++ requires a lot of discipline and care. That's why they're generally best avoided.

Comment: You haven't stated anywhere that the array is already sorted. Is it? This solution appears to assume that the array is sorted.

Comment: Take out the redundant casts in your code, they make the code harder to read

Comment: Yes, in the prompt it says to assume that the array is sorted ascending. Thanks!

Comment: *[...] not sure how to properly use pointers and Googling doesn't reveal too helpful results*. Really? Huston, we have a problem with Google.

Comment: You're not actually in a C++ class. It seems like you're in a C class.

Comment: Well, I mean the language we're learning is C++. The class may be named "Programming Fundamentals II" but the only language that we're learning about currently is C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea here, but you're computing your offsets wrong.

Here's an idea:

```
size_t median = sizeArray / 2;

return (pArray[median] + pArray[median+1]) / 2;
```

Don't forget this will fail if the values exceed `int` bounds, and additionally you should be using `size_t` to express sizes as that should never be negative.

Additionally, there's no point in casting the result of an `int` calculation to int.

Regarding this C++ lesson, I think anything that bucks the principles laid out in the Standard Library better have a good reason for doing so. While an academic exploration of the benefits of pointers vs. iterators vs. references is always encouraged, advocating pointers "whenever possible" is a bad plan and comes from a C mindset.

In a modern C++ course this assignment would revolve around computing the median of an unsorted Standard Library container of an arbitrary type by defining a template function.

Answer (score 1):

just so you can get a concrete feel regarding what people were talking about when they said 'modern c++ doesnt use pointer' etc.

One alternative is to use std::vector

```
int medianArray(const std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    int sizeArray = vec.size();
    if(sizeArray % 2 == 1)
    {
        return (vec[((int)(sizeArray/2)) -1 ] + vec[((int)(sizeArray/2)) +1 ]) / 2;
    }
    else
        return vec[(int) sizeArray/2];
}
```

note that vector knows how big it is. It also wont run off either end if you use `vec.at(index)`